# Equivalence of there being an $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$ and there being an $x>0$.

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$ a vector. Suppose that there exists an $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax=b$.
How do I show that it follows that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:Ax=b,x\geq0\}\neq\emptyset$?

Suppose the $x$ from the assumption is greater than or equal to $0$, then the statement holds evidently.
Now suppose $x<0$, then we take $y\equiv-x$. But then we don't have $Ay=b$. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by $x\geq0$ ?

Comment: Yeah, vectors are not orderable so what does $x\geq 0$ even mean?

Comment: @Baloown it means that all coefficients of $x$ are $\geq 0$.

Comment: @ZelosMalum see comment above

Answer (score 2):

This statement is false. For example take $m=n=1$, $A=1$, $b=-1$. The only $x\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $Ax=b\iff x=-1$ is $x=-1$. Then $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,;\,Ax=b,x\geq0\}=\varnothing.$